# How to edit this dynamically input textarea javascription

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this script to create a food & drinks menu, I just found this javascript on a website i don't know much about it but it works really well.

Im going to have a button to input entries for lots of different meal types, for example, Breakfast, Drinks, Dinner, Dessert etc etc.

How can i edit this so the textbox name is breakfast_selection[] or dinner_selection[]?

Also when i click the "Add Option" button, How can i have it so it says "Option 1: Textbox" then when they hit another textbox it says "Option 2: Textbox"

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add() {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("name", "selection[]");


    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
    var br = document.createElement("br");
    foo.appendChild(br);    
}

</SCRIPT>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action="testforms.php">
<p><b>Add a Menu Set</b></p>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">Menu Set Name</td>
        <td width="75%">
            <p><input type="text" name="setname" size="50"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="75%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="75%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" colspan="2"><b>Breakfast <INPUT type="button" value="Add Option" onclick="add(document.forms[0].text)"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" colspan="2">
        <span id="fooBar"> </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can i edit this so the textbox name is breakfast_selection[] or dinner_selection[]?

Change

```
element.setAttribute("name", "selection[]");
```

to

```
element.setAttribute("name", "breakfast_selection[]");
```

> Also when i click the "Add Option" button, How can i have it so it says "Option 1: Textbox" then when they hit another textbox it says "Option 2: Textbox"

Add a variable `i` to keep track of number of options. See the code below-

Update as per OP comment

Change

```
<td width="100%" colspan="2"><b>Breakfast <INPUT type="button" value="Add Option" onclick="add(document.forms[0].text)"/></td>
```

to

```
<td width="100%" colspan="2"><b>Breakfast <INPUT type="button" value="Add Option" onclick="add('breakfast')"/><br>
Lunch <INPUT type="button" value="Add Option" onclick="add('lunch')"/></td>
```

Update the script

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
var i = 1;
function add(orderType) {

//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");
//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", "text");
element.setAttribute("name", orderType + "_selection[]");


var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

//Append the element in page (in span).
//Create the option text
var a = document.createTextNode("option " + i + ": ");
foo.appendChild(a);
foo.appendChild(element);
var br = document.createElement("br");
foo.appendChild(br);
i++;    
}

</SCRIPT>
```

See demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P7Rks/)

Comment: Thanks it is working well, However im going to have many buttons, Like a button for dinner, a button for dessert a button for drinks later on. Once ive added that how can i change the dinner_selection[] based on which button they've pressed?

Comment: Add a parameter to the add() function, e.g. "form_name". You'd then have the event call the function with the form name you wish to add. E.g. <input ... onclick="add('dinner_selection')"> / function add(form_name) { /*...*/ element.setAttribute("name", form_name+"[]"); /*...*/ }

Comment: thanks that works great, Is there a way to have separate options for each of the selections, for example, Breakfast: Option 1, Option 2, then Dinner: Option 1, Option 2. At the moment when i click add breakfast it says option 1, but then when i click add lunch it says option 2. Can i keep the options for each food course, if that makes sense.